# How can I compare Entered Email from the sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have creating a login form where I have created sqlite database,in this I want to compare Count or Email in database if my email is in database so it will check the password,or if my email is not in database so it will call the web service.

So how can I compare Email or check count which user enter from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In this method i check if the username already exists in the database or not.**

```
// Read Section
public Boolean checkUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_USERNAME }, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + "'" + username + "'",
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**In this method i pass in Username and Password to check if the credentials match and if they do i log them in.**

```
public Cursor login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_USERNAME }, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + "'" + username + "'"
            + "AND " + KEY_PASSWORD + "=" + "'" + password + "'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: public Boolean checkUsername(String email) throws SQLException {
     Cursor mCursor = db.query("select email from member where email + "=" + "'" + email + "'",null);

     if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

Comment: have a look at this Article: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842 it teaches you how to deal with SQLite

Answer (score 0):

use 
`rawquery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_DATABASE_TABLENAME WHERE username=? AND password=?",new String[] {username,password});` 
store it in a cursor object as `Cursor=db.rawquery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_DATABASE_TABLENAME WHERE username=? AND password=?",new String[] {username,password});` and check if the cursor is null or not, if not the check the `(cursor.getcount()>0)` to know whether error occurs or not, if it returns -1 error has occured. return to the mainActivity where the fuction is present and display the result in toast or someother way. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the query like this

```
Cursor cm = odb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
        DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " +
        KEY_ID + "=? AND " +
        KEY_DATE + "=?",
        new String[]{id, date});
```